# Solve multivariable inequlity and read the output correctly

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Hi I need to solve an inequality for multiple variables, and I do not understand in a good manner the results. The inequality that I tray to obtain is

$$ a+b+(2*c)+\sqrt{(-2\,c-b-a)^2-4\,(2\,c\,b+b\,a-3\,|d|^2)}\ge 0 $$

where $a$, $b$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I try to solve the inequality using

```
Reduce[{a+b+(2*c)+Sqrt[(-2*c-b-a)^2-4\,(2\,c\,b+b\,a-3*|d|^2)] >= 0 
         && a + b == 1 && c <= a && 0 <= a <= 1}, {d}]
```

I want to find a solution for `d` and I am not sure if I can do it only specifying `d` in the variables space or I need to use the complete list `{a,b,c,d}`. I know this is a simple question but I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Table[With[{d=RandomReal[{-1000,1000}]+I*RandomReal[{-1000,1000}]},
Simplify[a+b+2*c+ Sqrt[(-2*c-b-a)^2-4(2*c*b+b*a-3*Abs[d]^2)]>=0, a+b==1 && c<=a && 0<=a<=1 && Element[a|b|c,Reals]]],{1000}]`

Comment: `d=r+I*i; Reduce[a+b+2*c+ Sqrt[(-2*c-b-a)^2-4(2*c*b+b*a-3*Abs[d]^2)]<0 && a+b==1 && c<=a && 0<=a<=1 && Element[a|b|c|r|i,Reals],{r,i}]`

Comment: Thanks. So I can only specify the variable that I want to obtain the inequality and not the whole of variables, did I understand correctly?

Comment: You can ask for the whole of variables or only some variables. Sometimes `Solve` or `Reduce` is faster or slower if you only ask for some variables and I do not know why. Often `Reduce` or `Solve` is much slower if you ask it for only Real solutions and I do not know why. But it appears that your original inequality is true for all values of d.

Comment: @Bill Oh, Thanks for the explanation, now I understand more the output of `Reduce`,